# File descriptor does write data in C

Tags: c, http, networking, libevent

I am using the [joyent http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) and lib event to create my own simple web server in C.

I have it connecting to the port and receiving the HTTP requests fine, however, I am not able to send a response using the socket.

So in one window I enter:

`$ curl localhost:5555/a.txt`

and in my server I receive and correctly handled it. TO the point I do the following:

```
   http_data_cb* message_complete_req_callback(http_parser* parser)
{
    int i;
    http_request_t* http_request = parser->data;
    http_response_t* http_response = generate_response(http_request);
    printf("Writing %d:\n%s", strlen(http_response->full_message), http_response->full_message);
    i = write(http_request->fd, http_response->full_message, strlen(http_response->full_message));
    fsync(http_request->fd);
    printf("Wrote: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints the following:

```
Writing 96:
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Tue, 04 Aug 2015 10:20:58 AEST
Server: mywebserver/jnd
Connection: close

Wrote: 96
```

However my `curl` instance doesn't receive anything. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you cast `http_request` to the type it already has? In any case, code that isn't a minimal complete example is difficult to handle for us.

Comment: Also your `printf` calls are bogus and shouldn't have passed a decent compiler: the correct format for `size_t` is `%zu` and your last one has a `%d` and no function argument for it. This alone could be a reason that your program crashes.

Comment: What was the value of `i` returned by `write()`? and why didn't you test it for an error? And why are you calling `printf()` with a `"%d"` format and no argument?

Comment: Sorry @JensGustedt I fixed that up and it seems to say it printed the correct number of bytes present.

Answer (score 0):

Your response contains no data, just headers. Curl strips off the headers and just prints the content.  Not only that but you're responding with `HTTP/1.0` which is a *long* way out of date.  As it happens, the `Connection: close` only makes sense in 1.1 as 1.0 does not support keeping a connection open.

For curl to report anything you need to send some content.  I'd expect the output to be something like:

```
Writing 128:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Tue, 04 Aug 2015 10:20:58 AEST
Server: mywebserver/jnd
Connection: close
Content-Length: 12

Hello World
Wrote: 128
```

Which would trigger curl to print:

```
Hello World
```

Notice the 12 character content length includes 1 character for the line feed.  The content is `Hello World<lf>`.